# how to get screen name of twitter using codebird js

Tags: twitter, titanium, titanium-mobile

1.2.GA and Android Emulator to run my Apps. AM using codebird to authorize my app in twitter and I got access token and using it how to get screen name or userid to fetch tweets of the user?

Answer (score 1):

When the user returns from the authentication screen, you need to trade
the obtained request token for an access token, using the OAuth verifier.
As discussed in the README section ‘Usage example,’ you use a call to
`oauth/access_token` to do that.

The API reply to this method call tells you details about the user that just logged in.
These details contain the **user ID** and the **screen name.**

Take a look at the returned data as follows:

```json
{
    oauth_token: "14648265-rPn8EJwfB**********************",
    oauth_token_secret: "agvf3L3**************************",
    user_id: 14648265,
    screen_name: "myx",
    httpstatus: 200
}
```

If you need to get more details, such as the user’s latest tweet,
you should fetch the complete User Entity.  The simplest way to get the
user entity of the currently authenticated user is to use the
`account/verify_credentials` API method.  In Codebird, it works like this:

```js
cb.__call(
    "account_verifyCredentials",
    {},
    function (reply) {
        console.log(reply);
    }
);
```

I suggest to cache the User Entity after obtaining it, as the
`account/verify_credentials` method is rate-limited by 15 calls per 15 minutes.